# get data from fragment to main activity null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a problem that i cant find anywhere to solve, i am learning android studio from udemy, and the way the professor do fragment exercises dont work on me. He makes 2 fragments, one for list and one for details, the problem is when i am trying to componets to be read from mainactivity to run my tasks, there  is a NullPointerException. Here is my Code:

DetailFragment

```
public class DetailFrag extends Fragment
```

{

```
ImageView imageView;
TextView tvName, tvTel;




private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public DetailFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static DetailFrag newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    DetailFrag fragment = new DetailFrag();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    
}
```

}

ListFragment

`public class ListFrag extends Fragment` {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
View view;


public ListFrag() {


}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    myAdapter = new PersonAdapter(this.getActivity(), ApplicationClass.people);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

}

MainActivity
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PersonAdapter.ItemClicked` {

```
TextView tvName,tvTel;
EditText etName, etTel;
Button btnAdd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName)
    tvTel = findViewById(R.id.tvTel);
    etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etTel = findViewById(R.id.etTel);
    btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}



@Override
public void onItemClicked(int index) {
    tvName.setText(ApplicationClass.people.get(index).getName());
    tvTel.setText(ApplicationClass.people.get(index).getTelNr());

}
```

}

Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerfragments, PID: 31089
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.recyclerfragments.MainActivity.onItemClicked(MainActivity.java:43)
        at com.example.recyclerfragments.PersonAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(PersonAdapter.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7575)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7548)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:837)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28933)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
```

Activity Main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="com.example.recyclerfragments.ListFrag"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
            android:name="com.example.recyclerfragments.DetailFrag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView3"
            android:name="com.example.recyclerfragments.AddPersonFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_person" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: yes sorry i added

Comment: Could you please post your `activity_main.xml` as well

Comment: yes i am sorry i am new and i tried my best to make the question

Comment: The error tells you. If can't seem to find the Button view. Double check that you have set THAT id to the Button.

Comment: in first i put wrong message, i changed it, the exception is different as the last you saw, sorry for the mistake

Comment: It still tells you. There is no `TextView` in the `MainActivity`. I think you are trying to change `TextView` that is in the `Fragment`.

Comment: yeah the instructor of the exercise, tells that you can call by id items of fragments in main activity and edit them, is there possible way or i have to find another solution

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you are right, next time i will make a better format of my problem, my problem solve by the second answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the stacktrace given your issue is that `tvTel` or `tvName` is null i.e. the view you are trying to reference is not available on MainActivity. Reading your comments on the question it seems these views are present on Fragment and not on MainActivity.

> Views of a fragment can be accessed on an Activity if and only if
> fragment is attached to that Activity.

What it means in your code is that when you tried to use findViewById in onCreate of your MainActivity your fragment was not attached to your activity causing findViewById to return null.

Now to make your `onItemClicked` work you need shift findViewById to `onItemClicked`

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(int index) {
    if(tvName == null)
       tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvName.setText(ApplicationClass.people.get(index).getName());
 
    if(tvTel == null)
       tvTel = findViewById(R.id.tvTel);
    tvTel.setText(ApplicationClass.people.get(index).getTelNr());

}
```

Above will fixed your issue of null view reference if fragment containing these view ids is attached to the activity.